# Quick Ruby Batch renamer

Tags: ruby, rename, strip

I am trying to tie in a few different scripts I have noticed here and here [link text](http://maravan.wordpress.com/2006/10/16/extending-the-ruby-strip-method/)
Trying to get a basic script that will allow me to strip characters or rename files given a directory characters and file extension by user.

I am struggling to tie it all together. This is where I am so far.

```
    require 'fileutils'

define renamer(strip, stripdetails) 
# So this is a strip function.

    def strip(str,char)
   new_str = ""
   str.each_byte do |byte|
      new_str << byte.chr unless byte.chr == char
   end
   new_str
end
# and then retrieve details from user.

#Get directory of files to be changed.
def stripdetails(strip myname)
 puts "Enter Directory containing files"
 STDOUT.flush
 oldname = gets.chomp
 puts "what characters do you want to remove"
 str = gets.chomp
 puts "what file extension do files end in?"
 fileXt = gets.chomp
 end

#And I found this from stackoverflow(I don't have enuff credits to post another hyperlink)
old_file = "oldname"
new_file = strip(oldname,str)
FileUtils.mv(old_file, new_file)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what isn't working. What errors are you seeing, or how isn't it working as you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a refactoring of your code. It's not entirely clear from your question or your code, but I'm assuming you want to remove given characters from each filename in a directory.

Note that strip() method you copied from a blog post is entirely unnecessary, as it is a poor reimplementation of the built-in `tr()` method.

```
#Given a directory, renames each file by removing
#specified characters from each filename

require 'fileutils'

puts "Enter Directory containing files"
STDOUT.flush
dir = gets.chomp
puts "what characters do you want to remove from each filename?"
remove = gets.chomp
puts "what file extension do the files end in?"
fileXt = gets.chomp

files = File.join(dir, "*.#{fileXt}")
Dir[files].each do |file|
  new_file = file.tr(remove,"")
  FileUtils.mv(file, new_file)
end
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to do! Thanks for the info regarding strip ad tr. I am learning at the moment so reading books and searching online code. Not always is the code or advice online accurate or the best.  Thanks Very much for your assistance Mark.

Comment: I notice though that when i exceute the code and it asks for the location, I cannot paste a directory location, I have to manually type it. Is there anyway around that?

Answer (score 0):

This program never calls your `stripdetails` method. Try removing the `def stripdetails..` and `end` lines on your "Get directory of files to be changed" block, so that code runs in the same scope.